# Sharing image on facebook and twitter from QtQuick application

Tags: facebook, qt, twitter, nokia, qml

I have a nokia Qt application (QtQuick QML App) that should share an image on facebook and twitter . is there is any way to do that ?

Comment: Using google I found http://code.google.com/p/qttwitter/ within 2 seconds. For facebook, I don't know a Qt API, but the official Facebook API isn't that difficult.

Comment: There is the official Qt Twitter example: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/demos-declarative-twitter.html But I'm not sure whether they post images or just read the feed.

Comment: Ok, forget the Twitter example; they are only reading from twitter.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, yes.

Long answer, yes. You'll need to decide how you want to post it but both Facebook and Twitter have exposed APIs for uploading images to their services, or you can post it off to an image hosting service like YFrog or TwitPic then use the returned URL with the Facebook & Twitter APIs to share the link.

I'm not sure on Facebook but there's definitely a Twitter Qt library that'll play nice, I'd assume there's one for Facebook but I've never had need to look into one.

Edit: here's the Qt Twitter lib I've looked at before, had to dig into my GitHub bookmarks https://github.com/minimoog/QTweetLib.

Answer (score 2):

you can do actions on Facebook as well as described on Facebook Graph 
that api can be used by javascript QML